# I might get fired tomorrow

Tags: riddle, rhyme

There was once a small cog who turnd round by day.
He did without *p*ressure nor greese.
I asked the sm*a*ll cog "Wh*y* you do such round things?"
He just smild and he turnd with such ease.

He turnd and he turnd with such effortless *g*race,
Then he went and he turnd r*o*und s*o*me more.
I thought "Turn with no greese? There's no en*d* to this! Cease!"
But he turned and turnd sin decor.

He eventually seized, and I sat there and cried.
"My small cog, what a *w*aste; I shall miss."
And that, my small friend, is what c*o*mes to an end
To a great cog who g*r*inds with dismiss.

O*K*?

> C'mon, take a guess! It's probably right.

Comment: There are 2 extra e's and 6 missing.

Comment: 24 hours later and I would suggest some sort of signal gun.

Comment: The italicized letters spell out "pay good work".

Comment: Can we get a hint?

Comment: Love the poem.  But it's unclear to me what exactly we are supposed to be guessing.

Comment: So, i don't know, guess?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the answer is

> a volunteer worker who gets dismissed.

Firstly, we have the title and italicised hint:

> the title about getting fired, and the italic letters read "*pay good work*" because someone who does good work should get paid for it.

The cog in the machine

> is a common metaphor for referring to workers who do a job as part of some greater whole (like a factory or any other workplace with many employees).

Turning without grease

> means working without getting paid, i.e. volunteer labour. You ask the cog/worker why he keeps going without grease/payment, and say there's no point.

Eventually the cog seizes,

> and the volunteer worker gets fired from their job. I say fired instead of quit, because of the word "dismiss" at the very end of the poem.

On a meta level, could this be

> a reference to [the situation of Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/278659), a volunteer moderator who did a lot of unpaid work maintaining Stack Exchange sites until she got fired a few months ago?

Comment: You know, I like your answer better. Nice job:)

Comment: Yeah, I felt like this is hinting towards some connection a bit more *abstract*/indirect than your answer(s).

Comment: Oh, I can definitely see that now. Darn hindsight. Perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

New guess

> A moon face accessory dial on a clock (grandfather clock)

Because

> It rotates each day with the time movement
>  clocks have gears (cogs)
>  The moon, if I remember correctly, has a face (man in the moon)
>  It will stop if you don't wind the clock
>  As for getting fired tomorrow, you may have been in charge of winding the clock.(tomorrow could reference time/clock)
>  "pay good work" found from the comments by Duck suggests you will not get paid.

Previous guess

> A quarter (or dime)
>  Cog shaped, you can flip it all day with your finger
>  Has a face on one side and decorations on the other
>  Must have spent it or lost it 
>  I don't know why you would get fired unless you were guarding Uncle Scrooge's lucky dime and lost it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this:

> A tribute to Shog9?
>  Maybe to draw attention to the [go fund me page](https://www.gofundme.com/f/thanking-josh-heyer-for-shaping-stack-overflow)

Basically for similar reasons to Rand al'Thor but a little more specific.

I.e.

> The whole poem is about a volunteer who gets dismissed
>  Italics spell out *paygoodwork* maybe a request by op for SE to pay community managers?

Also:

> There are **9** typo's throughout the post (missing e's or and an e where there should be an a)

Comment: It looks like this riddle was posted 2 weeks before that specific event was made public.

Comment: @MacGyver88 oops you're right - this is why I shouldn't answer questions at the end of the day... Unless the OP knew something we didn't!

Comment: I thought of this too, but ... yeah, what @Mac said :-)